# Changing style of a-tag on click

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I am trying to find a way where when one of the links below is clicked, similarly to the `nav-tabs` class in Bootstrap, the current link style changes to the `active` style and the previously clicked link reverts back to normal style. Does Bootstrap 5 have a quick way of changing the style or does it need to be done through normal CSS/JS?

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column">
   <li><a class="nav-link link-light" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" asp-route-SortString="Award" asp-route-StatusId="@Context.Request.Query["StatusId"]">Highest Awarded</a></li>
   <li><a class="nav-link link-light" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" asp-route-SortString="Update" asp-route-StatusId="@Context.Request.Query["StatusId"]">Last Updated</a></li>
   <li><a class="nav-link link-light" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" asp-route-SortString="Newest" asp-route-StatusId="@Context.Request.Query["StatusId"]">Date Added (Newest)</a></li>
   <li><a class="nav-link link-light" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" asp-route-SortString="Oldest" asp-route-StatusId="@Context.Request.Query["StatusId"]">Date Added (Oldest)</a></li>
</ul>
```

So, for instance, if I click on **Highest Awarded**, the previously clicked link reverts to normal style and **Highest Awarded** link adds `active` in its class, thus changing the style to that of `active`.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navs-tabs/#javascript-behavior

You can use Bootstrap's tabs to hide/show elements with data attributes. If you look at the example from the link, the first `<button>` has the data attributes `data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#home"`. This corresponds to a `tab-pane` with an id of `home`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("ul li").on("click",function(){
  $(this).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active")
})
```

```css
.active{
   color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column">
   <li><a class="nav-link link-light" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" asp-route-SortString="Award" asp-route-StatusId="@Context.Request.Query["StatusId"]">Highest Awarded</a></li>
   <li><a class="nav-link link-light" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" asp-route-SortString="Update" asp-route-StatusId="@Context.Request.Query["StatusId"]">Last Updated</a></li>
   <li><a class="nav-link link-light" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" asp-route-SortString="Newest" asp-route-StatusId="@Context.Request.Query["StatusId"]">Date Added (Newest)</a></li>
   <li><a class="nav-link link-light" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" asp-route-SortString="Oldest" asp-route-StatusId="@Context.Request.Query["StatusId"]">Date Added (Oldest)</a></li>
</ul>
```

This is a simple jquery workaround, you can also implement this using vanilla JS. You can add your required styles for the **active** class. I don't think we could achieve this only using bootstrap except 5.0. Feel free to comment if you couldn't get it.